# How do I make pip install binaries to a writable path?

Tags: python, permissions, pip

I have python 2.7 installed through homebrew and running `pip install -r requirements.txt` on a project's requirements file. The packages download, everything goes fine until it's time to link the binaries - then Pip tries to put the binaries for f2py (a dependency of a package in the requirements.txt file) into `/bin` and I'm left with this error:

```
IOError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/bin/f2py'
```

I don't have root access so I'd like for pip to put all binaries in `/usr/local/bin` instead. How do I tell pip to install binaries into that directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd create a *virtualenv* (install it with `pip` first), then use the virtualenv to install all your requirements. That way you both have a writable path and keep your global Python installation clean for other projects.

Alternatively, you could use the `--user` option to install in the [`site.USER_SITE`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/site.html#site.USER_SITE) location:

```
pip install --local virtualenv
```

or

```
pip install --local -r requirements.txt
```

See the [*User Installs* section](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#user-installs) in the documentation.

Comment: Thank you - I ended up using the --user option and that seemed to work alright.

Answer (score 2):

If you downloaded the package you can do

```
python setup.py install --user
```

pip now supports this behaviour by passing user to setup.py

```
pip install --user somepackage
```